# Oracle 10g Express / APEX

Tags: oracle

I downloaded the free 10g Express. When I tried downloading the "free" Application Express development tool version 3.2.1 it gave me an error message saying it could not find that download.  Anyone have any idea whats going on with this?

Comment: (Not a programming question) Apex is included in 10g Express. Version 3.2.1 can be downloaded from apex.oracle.com.

Answer (score 2):

The 3.2.1 install is available on [the Apex Download page](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/application_express/download.html), and the zip is definitely downloadable.

Comment: when i clicked on the download button, it said it wasnt available!.. same for previous versions.. think now they only allow to use on-line version (no more downloads)

Comment: @FrankDeveloper - You are logged into your OTN account?  You have accepted the OTN License?  Because I have xjust downloaded all 107MB of it, literally seconds ago.

Comment: yes i was login in with my registered OTN account and yes, i accepted the OTN license agreement, but when I clicked the 3.2.1 APEX Windows version download, it opened another window saying it couldnt find that link. the earlier versions produced the same results.

Comment: @FrankDeveloper - Are you using the page to which I linked?  There is no "Windows version" there is only the one zip for all platforms.

Comment: I repeat, the APEX zip file is not available, even the archived earlier versions!.. when I click to download any version of APEX, It opens another window with error 404 (link doesnt exist) then re-directs me to signup for online version.

Comment: @FrankDeveloper - We must be operating in different realities then, because I clearly was able to download a 107MB last night.  Twice in fact (the second time was a mistake).  And I can download it again *right now* from  http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/application_express/download.html   I don't know why you are getting a 404 error but the 3.2.1 zip *is available for download*.  So I think I have gone as far as I can to help you.  You could post to the OTN Downloads forum: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=36 but they'll tell you the same story.

Comment: ok, then there must be some kinda problem with my OTN account, but why was I able to download Oracle 10g, but not APEX is beyond me. Perhaps, if you still have the 107MB APEX zip file, could you send it to me?

Comment: send me an email to:  frank@frankcomputer.com and I will reply with snapshots of the screens/links I ahve been presented with, then you can get a better feel for what's going on with my situation.. maybe this will help resolve the problem.. i've already sent oracle an email requesting help, but haven't received a reply.